# Wix Bootstrapper Uninstallation

Tags: wix, wix-extension

I need to programatically access the uninstall location of the bootstrapper. I need this information because some files which will be needed by the packages in the chain during uninstall need to be moved here once all packages are successfully installed.

I might be required to modify the value of UninstallString in the registry to a different location and copy the bootstrapper executable and other required files to this location. Are there any side effects on doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the required files using payload. The files are packed into your boostrapper.exe and available during execution in the same folder your bootstrapper is executed. Add files required by you bootstrapper application to the payload of the bootstrapper application.

```
  <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id='ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost'>
    <Payload SourceFile='MyBA.dll' />
    <Payload SourceFile='BootstrapperCore.config' />
    ... place additional playload files here ...
  </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

You can access them from your bootstrapper code with

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "payloadfilename");
```

You can also add files to specific packages.

```
<ExePackage InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;"
            UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;" >
    <Payload SourceFile="payloadfilename"/>
  </ExePackage>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved this problem a little differently. Since a folder structure needs to be maintained for the files used during uninstallation, I defined my own un-install location and moved the required folders/files to this location once all the packages are successfully installed. During uninstall, in my  Custom bootstrapper application, I changed the current working directory to this predefined uninstall location. It then works fine, and all the packages in the chain can access the required files during uninstall.